# Generate powerset lazily

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation, powerset

I want to calculate powerset of a set. Because I don't need the whole powerset at a time, it's better to generate it lazily.

For example:

```
powerset (set ["a"; "b"; "c"]) =
seq {
  set [];
  set ["a"];
  set ["b"];
  set ["c"];
  set ["a"; "b"];
  set ["a"; "c"];
  set ["b"; "c"];
  set ["a";"b"; "c"];
}
```

Since the result is a sequence, I prefer it in the above order. How can I do it in an idomatic way in F#?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm going to use (based on BLUEPIXY's answer):

```
let powerset s =
    let rec loop n l =
        seq {
              match n, l with
              | 0, _  -> yield []
              | _, [] -> ()
              | n, x::xs -> yield! Seq.map (fun l -> x::l) (loop (n-1) xs)
                            yield! loop n xs
        }   
    let xs = s |> Set.toList     
    seq {
        for i = 0 to List.length xs do
            for x in loop i xs -> set x
    }
```

Thanks everyone for excellent input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let rec comb n l =
  match n, l with
  | 0, _  -> [[]]
  | _, [] -> []
  | n, x::xs -> List.map (fun l -> x ::l) (comb (n - 1) xs) @ (comb n xs)

let powerset xs = seq {
    for i = 0 to List.length xs do
      for x in comb i xs -> set x
  }
```

**DEMO**

```
> powerset ["a";"b";"c"] |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A");;
set []
set ["a"]
set ["b"]
set ["c"]
set ["a"; "b"]
set ["a"; "c"]
set ["b"; "c"]
set ["a"; "b"; "c"]
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: Note that you could make `comb` return a sequence as well, which would require less computation in certain cases if the entire powerset is not enumerated.

Answer (score 4):

From [*F# for Scientists*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/09/16/book-review-f-for-scientists.aspx), slightly modified to be lazy

```
let rec powerset s = 
  seq {
    match s with
    | [] -> yield []
    | h::t -> for x in powerset t do yield! [x; h::x]
  }
```

Comment: This is beautiful and efficient. The only problem is incorrect order :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using maths instead of recursion:

```
let powerset st =
    let lst = Set.toList st     
    seq [0..(lst.Length |> pown 2)-1] 
        |> Seq.map (fun i -> 
            set ([0..lst.Length-1] |> Seq.choose (fun x -> 
                if i &&& (pown 2 x) = 0 then None else Some lst.[x])))
```

Comment: see "I prefer it in the above order."

Comment: I see, but it says "I prefer". However my intention was mainly to show a different approach, with maths but still lazy.